# Autobiographies of Buddhist masters

Tags: history, texts, teachers, learning-materials

Can you recommend any good autobiographies of Buddhist teachers and monks? I'm currently reading [Getting Off, A Portrait of an American Buddhist Monk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9460900054) and I find it very interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I can thoroughly recommended [Dipa Ma-The Life and Legacy of a Buddhist Master](http://www.thezensite.com/ZenBookReviews/DipaMa_The_Life_and_Legacy_of_a_Buddhist_Master.htm), a short biography of [Dipa Ma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipa_Ma), She was an housewife, mother and highly developed Buddhist teacher living in Calcutta. I think it's inspirational, particularly for people interested in how to practice Buddhism in the modern world.

Also I've been personally recommended [Wild Ivy](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3995627-wild-ivy) which is an biography of [Hakuin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hakuin_Ekaku) the 18th century Japanese Zen master. I haven't personally read this but I have attended study groups when we have been taking reading from this and it is excellent.

Finally [Gautama Buddha: The Life and Teachings of The Awakened One](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10211707-gautama-buddha) is a well recommended recent biography of the original Buddhist teacher. I have received a fair few personal recommendations that this is a good one even if you think you are very familiar with the story of the historical Buddha.

Comment: These must be great books, even though OP asked about auto-biographies.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov hahahaha missed that. I'll let the answer stand though as they are great books. Still maybe someone has the proper answer

Answer (score 2):

Specifically of *auto*-biographies, I enjoyed [*Confession of a Buddhist Atheist* by Stephen Batchelor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0385527071) and of course [*Born In Tibet* by Chogyam Trungpa](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1570627142)

Of biographies, [Life of Milarepa](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0143106228), even if mythical, remains an inspiring life story.